# Thingsboard dynamically create devices

Tags: rest, mqtt, thingsboard

Is there any way of creating devices programmatically and get their tokens.
I have a project where I need to create "entities" in my application side dynamically. I want these to be able to send data to a dashboard where I want to see some features of these "entities". 
Since they are created on-the-fly during runtime, I was wondering if there's any way to create devices (or even other option) programmatically in order to allow this "entities" (that can be 1000s) to send data (over MQTT or REST) to Thingsboard.

Thanks...

Comment: can you provide an update? did you find a solution, was the answer below helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gateway with Thingsboard gateway API to create devices using MQTT with a single token (the one of the gateway, declared in devices a "is GATEWAY")